# WKWebview scrolls while selecting text

Tags: swift, scroll, wkwebview

I'm using WKWebView to present text with HTML using `loadHtmlString`.

I'm using `overflow: -webkit-paged-x` to create paging.

The problem is - when the user selects text, and getting near a side of the screen while selecting text, the scrollview starts to scroll to that side.

how can I cancel this behavior in a way that a selection of text will not invoke scrolling?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60548215/wkwebview-prevent-automatic-scrolling-triggered-by-user-text-selection

Comment: It is a duplicate but I asked first :)